# How can I fix the error RECEIVER_EXPORTED

Tags: android, kotlin

I encountered the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lyricsify/com.example.lyricsify.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.lyricsify:
> One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.lyricsify">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.spotify.music" />
    </queries>

    <permission android:name="com.example.lyricsify.CUSTOM_NFC_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lyricsify"
        tools:targetApi="34">


        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.lyricsify.SpotifyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged" />
                <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged" />
                <action android:name="com.spotify.music.queuechanged" />
                <action android:name="com.spotify.music.active" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried rebuilding and cleaning my project.
I also tried making the exported in true and false, but the app keeps on crashing